# How to use self signed certificat with Postman

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, postman, self-signed

I'm using Postman to test my API.

It works fine in dev env as I'm calling my server in http.
However on the acceptance testing platform, the server is in https and we are using self signed certificat.

When I try to make the call via Postman I get "Could not get any response" and it's written underneath that SSL connections are being blocked, with a link to [this page](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/).

However as notified in the comment, this does not work anymore for self signed ceritifcate and the latest chrome release.
For info, I'm using Version 59.0.3071.115 (Build officiel) (64 bits)

When I go into google settings, then certificates : chrome://settings/certificates
And I try to import an authority certificat, I get an error popin that says that my authority is not a certificat authority and it won't allow me to import it.

As I'm on linux, I tried to do what is detailed there : https://superuser.com/questions/1201552/not-a-certification-authority-while-importing-self-signed-certificate
But even though I see my certificat when I call

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L
```

It still won't allow me to import it in google.

So how can one use self signed certificat under linux with Postman ?

---

EDIT :  I was using the version from Chrome web store which is lacking SSL support. Downloaded the standalone and as @Pratik Mandrekar wrote it works fine!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable SSL certificate verification in Postman. Settings->SSL certificate verification as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that the version I'm using, from chrome shop (plugin) has a lot less option than the standalone. Downloaded the standalone after seeing your post and it works wonder. Thanks!

Comment: :) Yeah Google is sunsetting apps for Chrome https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html. So while the chrome plugin still tries to maintain parity there are a bunch of things that just cannot be built into it. Hence the standalone cross platform apps.

Comment: This worked for me, but the setting is ambiguous.  It doesn't prevent use of SSL certs, but it simply turns the error into a warning.  It's not well documented what turning off this setting actually does.  Once I did this the error turned into a warning. I wish that would have been made clear in the answer so I thought I'd post that comment.